# .Net Console app stopped in background

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on my server, I have .net core console application, I use this command to run my program in background

```
dotnet myapp.dll &

jobs
```

When I See the jobs it showed that stopped. 
How can i run my .net console application in background processes?

Comment: A loop inside main entry function?

Comment: @VMAtm Yes, it has.

Comment: Can you show us the code running?

Comment: I get the same issue with `dotnet run &`, but `dotnet myapp.dll &` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @Mahyar did you solve this?

Comment: @marto unfortunately not

Comment: @Mahyar I found a workaround with using "screen", basically it creates a terminal in the terminal and you can exit it and create something like a closure. Idea is that you won`t need to run it in the background but run it normally then ctrl+ad to detach screen from terminal and then exit.